# Trying to fill data in a table from multiple multiple table in Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fill a table in the view from multiple tables of oracle.
But not getting an exact idea of how to do.

After login, I am trying to fetch single value data from multiple tables with a single query. I mean I have 9 variables in which data is coming from the different table through a single query. and then I have to fill these values in a different column of a table in view

```
[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
    {
         dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
         model.DailyRmRec = GetDailyRmRec();
         model.CrfhStk = GetCrfhStk();
         model.HrIntrn = GetHrIntrn();
         model.CrfhIntrn = GetCrfhIntrn();
         model.HrWtW = GetHrWtW();
         model.HrWtF = GetHrWtF();
         model.CrfhWtW = GetCrfhWtW();
         model.CrfhWtF = GetCrfhWtF();
         model.HrBalToRol = GetHrBalToRol();
         model.CrfhBalToRol = GetCrfhBalToRol();
         return View("Home");
    }

public dynamic GetDailyRmRec()
{
 string HrStk_S="select  wt from hdata";
string  CrfhStk_S="Select wt from hdata";
.... similarly for all above model parameter each method is defined
}
```

These properties are defined in model

```
public class DailyRmRec
    {
        public int HrStk { get; set; }
        public int CrfhStk { get; set; }
        public int HrIntrn { get; set; }
        public int CrfhIntrn { get; set; }

    }     




public class ReadyAtSrc
    {
        public int HrWtW { get; set; }
        public int HrWtF { get; set; }
        public int CrfhWtW { get; set; }
        public int CrfhWtF { get; set; }
    }


 public class BalToRol
    {
        public int HrBalToRol { get; set; }
        public int CrfhBalToRol { get; set; }
    }
```

Expected: Individual values are coming from different table and all these values are stored in a separate individual variable and these variables will fill the different column of tables.
Actual: Trying to get data don't know the exact method of how to do and then fill a different column of the table in a view any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you use a stored procedure?

Comment: @Hoshani i am new to  MVC can you give ref to bind table with values coming from different table in stored procedure

Comment: [this](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/working-with-multiple-tables-in-mvc/) might help you a little

Comment: @Hoshani i want without entity framework do you have

Comment: you might want to refer to [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/francissvk/crud-operations-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-ado-net/), if it works for you, you should post a full detailed answer about it